# What software to use for cloning my ubuntu 20 live server (VPS)

Tags: backup, ubuntu, server

I have done too many configurations and installations on my Ubuntu server 20 on a VPS. I only have access to ubuntu (nothing else like BIOS).
Now I want to do a backup for the full VPS (80 GB) to copy it later to my other servers and VPS.
Please recommend me with any available and preferred easy software that could help